# How can a Colab notebook detect an error in a bash script/command

Tags: python, bash, google-colaboratory

If an error arises in a `%%bash` command, I'd like to stop execution in Colab.

The following approach uses flag files, which feels to me like a kludge.  Is there a better way?

```
import os
flagfile_path = '/content/job_completed.flag'
! rm $flagfile_path
```

```
%%bash -e -s $flagfile_path
  FLAGFILE_PATH=$1
  function mk_flag_file(){
    touch $FLAGFILE_PATH
  }
  echo Cmd1
  ls .
  echo Cmd2
  ls x
  echo Cmd3
  ls /content
  mk_flag_file
```

```
class BashScriptError(Exception):
  pass
if not os.path.exists(flagfile_path):
  raise BashScriptError
```